# Python: how to shorten this loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring

The code seems a bit long for something that trivial.

Is there a pythonic way to shorten it?

```
fruit = None
for _fruit in basket:
  if _fruit['name'] != 'banana':
    continue
  fruit = _fruit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fruit = None
for _fruit in basket:
    if _fruit['name'] == 'banana':
        fruit = _fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming basket is a list:

```
fruit = [x for x in basket if x != "banana"]
```

This also allows to have better performance due to comprehension list https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: This does not do the same thing, and also raises a SyntaxError

Comment: fixed. now it works

Comment: fruit = [x for x in basket if x != "banana"] ---> fruit = [x for x in basket if x['name'] != "banana"] ???

Comment: fruit = [x for x in basket if x != "banana"] ---> fruit = [x for x in basket if x['name'] != "banana"] ??? –

Answer (score -1):

Based on your initial conditions. Try this,

```py
fruit, = [_fruit for _fruit in basket if _fruit['name'] == 'banana'][-1:] or (None, )
```

This allows:

1. If there are multiple `_fruit`s have name `banana`, assign the last one to `fruit`.
2. If not, assign `None` to `fruit`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have in minimum code lines

```
1) 
try: fruit = [b  for b in basket if b['name'] == 'banana'][0]
except: fruit = None

2) 
a = [b  for b in basket if b['name'] == 'banana']
fruit = a[0] if a else None
```

But a better way would be to stop the loop whenever it finds 'banana':

```
fruit = None
for b in basekt: 
    if b['name'] == 'banana': 
        fruit = b 
        break
```

Comment: @Mr.B. These are all wrong, as they find the *first* banana. The original code finds the *last* one. And the first two are unpythonic and waste memory, and the last one has a typo.